# Why does compiling a shared object with GCC always result in undefined references to main?

Tags: gcc, linker, shared-libraries, symbols

I'm running Solaris, so it's possible that this is specific to running GCC on Solaris. If I use GCC to generate a shared object, and then run nm on it to see undefined symbols, there will always be a reference to main:

```
[624]     |         0|       0|NOTY |GLOB |0    |UNDEF  |main
```

If I manually generate the same shared object using ld, the reference to main doesn't exist. If I run nm on the system libraries in /usr/lib, none of them appear to have references to main. Only shared libraries I compile myself with GCC.

Apps compiled against these shared libraries work fine and without errors. But I still don't understand why the reference to main is there in the first place. Any clues?

Comment: Could you post the command you use to compile your shared object ?

Comment: To expand on delroth's comment, you are most likely leaving out some flag that GCC should pass to the loader to tell it to just create a shared lib and not try to link against libc.  

If I recall correctly, invoking gcc with the -v flag will make it print the exact commands it's executing, and will show the flags it's giving ld.  You can compare that with your own ld command and it should become clear.

Comment: I don't think there's anything exotic in here, and it has the -G to indicate creation of a shared library:

g++ -Wl,-R/export/home/joeg/fresh/lib -L/opt/tradelink/g++lib6/lib -Wl,-R/opt/tradelink/g++lib6/lib -L/opt/app/g++lib6/toast-1.1/lib -L/opt/app/g++lib6/boost-1.34/lib -Wl,-G -fpic -o libprice.so  *.fpo -Wl,-Bstatic -ltoast_datetime -ltoast_assert -ltoast_typeinfo -ltoast_async -lboost_filesystem-gcc42-mt -lboost_date_time-gcc42-mt -lboost_regex-gcc42-mt -lboost_signals-gcc42-mt -lboost_thread-gcc42-mt -lboost_program_options-gcc42-mt -Wl,-Bdynamic -lrt -lpthread

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the `-shared` option in your `gcc` link command line.

EDIT: and you forgot `-fPIC` option on your compile command line (which is causing all the relocation errors at link time).

If you still get relocation errors with `-fPIC` on all compile lines, then you should rebuild all the archive libraries which you link in (`libtoast_datetime`, `libtoast_assert`, etc.) with `-fPIC` as well.

Comment: I thought that's what the -G accomplished? Anyway, trying with "-shared" I get a million linker errors about Unwind_resume missing in boost. If I try again with "-shared-libgcc" then I get no errors, but the .so has a reference to main again O_o

Comment: Also strangely they're text relocation errors, not undefined reference errors.

Comment: It turns out you were right, my testing just wasn't working because I don't write the link line myself, my make tool does, so I'd been copy and pasting the link line it'd generated and tweaking it, and I accidentally was using a link line from a shared build in a static sandbox ;p

Separate question -- why has this worked in the past? All the shared objects here have been built with -fPIC in the past, but *not* with -shared and have worked fine. This didn't become an issue until I started work to make linking more precise (only pulling in exactly what's needed).